# Error: $resource:badcfg Unable to update user data with ngResource

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngresource

I am trying to edit a resource and display the user data on my edit form. All of my other CRUD operations are working except for update. Can someone help me understand and correct this error:

Error: $resource:badcfg Response does not match configured parameter

Here is the code:

```
form.adults.html

<td><a ui-sref="form.adults-edit()"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Edit</button></a></td>

app.js

var app = angular.module("LunchApp", ["ngVidBg", "ngAnimate","ui.router",'ngResource']);
app.config(function($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider) {

  $stateProvider

 .state('form.adults-edit', {
    url: '/adults/{{adult._id}}/edit',
    controller: "EditAdultController",
    templateUrl: "views/a-edit.html"
  })

 $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('login');
  });

services.js

app.service("AdultService",['$resource', function($resource){
    return $resource('/api/adults/:id', {id: '@_id'}, {
        update : {
            method: 'PUT'
        }
    });
}]);

controllers.js

app.controller("EditAdultController", function($scope, $location, $stateParams, AdultService){
  AdultService.get({id: $stateParams.id},function(adult){
    $scope.adult = adult;
    console.log(adult);
  }, function(err){
    $state.go('form.adultsInHousehold1');
  });
  $scope.editAdult = function(adult){
    console.log("This is working!");
    $scope.adult.$update(function(){
       $state.go('form.adultsInHousehold1');
    });
  };
});
```

Comment: There may be some useful error messages in your server logs.

Comment: Is that really the complete error message? The usual "badcfg" suspect is when your $resource-function is expecting an object, but is getting an array response or the other way around. The simple fix is to change your  "update" command. Try `{method: 'PUT', isArray: false}` or  if that doesn't help also try `isArray: true`.

Comment: [$resource:badcfg] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.5/$resource/badcfg?p0=Error%20in%20resource…A%20%7B3%7D%20%7B4%7D)&p1=get&p2=object&p3=array&p4=GET&p5=%2Fapi%2Fadults

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$resource/badcfg?p0=Error%20in%20resource%20configuration%20for%20action%20%60%7B0%7D%60.%20Expected%20response%20to%20contain%20an%20%7B1%7D%20but%20got%20an%20%7B2%7D%20(Request:%20%7B3%7D%20%7B4%7D)&p1=get&p2=object&p3=array&p4=GET&p5=%2Fapi%2Fadults